# How to source .qmd file / How to only run code chunks of a .qmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, quarto

I would like to only run the Code Chunks of my Quarto document using a command similar to the shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+R) in RStudio. But I am looking for a way to do this in cases where I'm not working in an IDE.

So far I only found the workaround, to create a .R script using `knitr::purl` and the `source` this file:

```
knitr::purl(input = "my/file.qmd", output = "my/output_file")
source("my/output_file")
```